# Sign multiple jars with the same signature

Tags: java, jar, signature

I was trying to sign `TestJnlp.jar` using the following commands.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias myFirstKey -keystore myKeystore -validity 360
jarsigner.exe -keystore myKeystore -verbose TestJnlp.jar myKey
```

I need to sign another jar file (`swt-win32-windows-x86.jar`).

How do I sign both of these jars with the same signature and what is the "signature"?

Comment: Fixed some formatting and tried to clear up content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is “Sign all jars with same signature”?

What it is is "sloppy terminology"!

What they really mean is "Sign all JARs with the same *key*".

So what you should do is this:

```
...> keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias myFirstKey -keystore myKeystore -validity 360

...> jarsigner.exe -keystore myKeystore -verbose TestJnlp.jar myKey

...> jarsigner.exe -keystore myKeystore -verbose SomeOther.jar myKey
```

---

For more information, read the Java Tutorial page on JAR signing:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html